# Exchange 2010 powershell error for Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange

Just installed Ex2k10 in an organization with an existing Ex2k7 server. Ex2k10 is not receiving any traffic yet. When I try to run the Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory cmdlet from Exchange shell, I get the following error:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory
Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory" command...
WARNING: An unexpected error has occurred and a Watson dump is being generated: Retrieving the COM class factory for
remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine tank.example.com failed due to
the following error: 80040154.
Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine ta
nk.example.com failed due to the following error: 80040154.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigur
   ationTasks.GetMobileSyncVirtualDirectory
```

When I run this cmdlet from Ex2k7 shell, it replies correctly with Ex2k7 and Ex2k10 servers. I haven't been able to figure out what to do about this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Intial research about your problem does show that this is a common problem between Exchange 2010 and 2007, there are two suggested ways to solve it:

1- Install the latest SPs and update rollups for both servers: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2538958

2- Disable your firewall (Crazy, but they say it works): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/001ca054-b7da-46e5-b44d-1162e52c60a9/exchange-2007-sp3-rollup-1-emc-error-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-remote-component-with

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found a KB at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2537099 for anyone running into the same problem where they receive error # 80040154 when configuring Exchange 2010 CAS